constant-memory vectorized sum of function values with jax
Let's say I have a function f that takes an integer argument and returns a fixed-size array. I want to evaluate the sum of f(i) over range(N) for some large N, such that storing all values in memory becomes problematic. With a simple for loop I can fix this easily and evaluate the sum with constant memory use:
import jax.numpy as jnp
f = lambda i : i*jnp.identity(1000)+i  # A simple function that will quickly eat up memory
result = 0. # Generic initialization - works with any array-like function.
for i in range(N):
    result += f(i)

but then the for loop is very slow. On the other hand, if I write this using jax vmap,
result = jnp.sum(vmap(f)(jnp.arange(N)),axis=0)

I'm also in trouble because all values are evaluated before the sum is done, and I'm eating up all the memory.
What would be the right way to vectorize this sum using jax? I've looked for it for a while, and couldn't find an elegant solution.

The issue is that vmap will vectorize your function, and in your case vectorization involves creating an array of size (N, 1000, 1000).
The for loop approach is fine, and I suspect it will actually lead to quite fast runtime in the end, but because JAX flattens Python control flow and sends it to the compiler, you'll generally run into very long compile times when using large for loops (see JAX FAQ: Benchmarking JAX code for tips on how to effectively benchmark compile vs run time).
In the exact example you gave, I'd probably re-express the computation to be more efficient: this gives the same result in closed-form:
(N * (N - 1) // 2) * (identity(1000) + 1)

You may be able to do something similar in your real example.
In the general case of iterations where vectorization leads to out-of-memory errors, the best option will probably be jax.lax.fori_loop, which will have slower runtime than a vectorized solution (because each step must be done sequentially rather than in parallel) but avoids constructing the broadcasted array, and will have much faster compile time than a Python for loop:
result = jax.lax.fori_loop(1, N, lambda i, val: val + f(i), init_val=f(0))


Thanks for the reply. So, essentially you're saying that there is no simple solution (the real problem does not admit an analytical solution).

I think the fori_loop solution I gave is pretty simple?

Agreed, but it's not vectorized, while on principle it should be possible I think, since each loop step is independent.

Yes, it’s possible to vectorize if you have enough memory to hold the full vectorized computation…

...and vectorizing WITHOUT using extensive memory was the point of the question. Anyway, thanks for your help, I'll take it as a "not possible"! :-)

Yeah, I think probably "not possible by definition". Vectorization implies the operation is in-memory; if you want to do sections of the operation in sequence without holding the whole problem in memory, you need sequential rather than vectorized operations.
